# What is the greatest theoretical delta value?

Tags: options, american-options, greeks, delta

In a few options positions I'm currently holding I noticed delta values of ~0.6 while gamma is ~1.0 which surprised me as I thought delta can never be greater than 1 - meaning for every 1\$ move in the underlying security, option price moves for 1\$ (x100) as well. According to [this](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/49232/possibility-of-delta-greater-than-1) delta **can** be greater than 1. However, I'm curious how high it can go and what does delta of 1.5 mean in terms of a price change? Does it mean that option price moves 1.5\$ for every 1\$ move in the underlying security?
[Options Greeks screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kh9Kk.jpg)

Comment: Gamma is the rate of change of the delta for a small change in the price of the underlying asset. Delta doesn't go to 1.5. I recommend you check how your provider quotes (defines) gamma.

Comment: [This answer](https://quant.stackexchange.com/a/65827/54838) shows different computations for gamma in Black76.

Comment: Coincidentally, I just answered your question indirectly by answering another question [here](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/68352/can-gamma-of-an-option-be-greater-than-its-delta/68359#68359). Hope it helps.

Comment: @JanStuller - Thanks. Can we think of gamma as a sort of "acceleration" of change in delta? As soon as delta starts changing, acceleration will slow down.

Comment: Delta can be greater than 1 if you have formulas in your payoff function.  Easy example is a basket option.  Say the weights are 2, -2, 1, -1.  Then your respective maximum Deltas are 2, -2, 1, -1.  I see this come up all the time with exotic payoffs.